# Get next value per group based on next ordered group value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to find the next value per group based on the next ordered number. In the following reproducible example in group 2 we have twice subgroup 1, which means that for both of these values the next value should be from the subgroup 2 which is 4. Here is some reproducible data (df `dput` below):

```
> df
   group subgroup value
1      1        1     9
2      1        2     8
3      1        3     7
4      2        1     8
5      2        1     6
6      2        2     4
7      2        3     2
8      3        1     2
9      3        1     3
10     3        2     7
11     3        3     9
```

If we try to use it with the next row number we get of course the **wrong** value like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(next_value = value[row_number()+1])
#> # A tibble: 11 × 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    group subgroup value next_value
#>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1        1     9          8
#>  2     1        2     8          7
#>  3     1        3     7         NA
#>  4     2        1     8          6
#>  5     2        1     6          4
#>  6     2        2     4          2
#>  7     2        3     2         NA
#>  8     3        1     2          3
#>  9     3        1     3          7
#> 10     3        2     7          9
#> 11     3        3     9         NA
```

My **desired output** should look like this:

```
   group subgroup value next_value
1      1        1     9          8
2      1        2     8          7
3      1        3     7         NA
4      2        1     8          4
5      2        1     6          4
6      2        2     4          2
7      2        3     2         NA
8      3        1     2          7
9      3        1     3          7
10     3        2     7          9
11     3        3     9         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to get the next ordered upcoming value per group using R?

---

`dput` of df:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), subgroup = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3), value = c(9, 8, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2, 
2, 3, 7, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the subgroups are in order and continuous from 1:n, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(next_value = value[match(subgroup, subgroup - 1)], .by = group)

     group subgroup value next_value
1      1        1     9          8
2      1        2     8          7
3      1        3     7         NA
4      2        1     8          4
5      2        1     6          4
6      2        2     4          2
7      2        3     2         NA
8      3        1     2          7
9      3        1     3          7
10     3        2     7          9
11     3        3     9         NA
```

If they are in order but are not continuous or are a factor or character, you can do:

```
df |>
  mutate(tmp = match(subgroup, unique(subgroup)),
         next_value = value[match(tmp, tmp - 1)],
         tmp = NULL, .by = group)
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Turn the value column into lists
2. Find the first value in next row's value list
3. Unnest all the lists again

```
library("tidyverse")

df |> 
  summarise(value = list(value), .by = c(group, subgroup)) |>
  mutate(n = map(lead(value), ~ .x[[1]]), .by = group) |>
  unnest(c(value, n))
```